# Insert picture in Ask Ubuntu

Tags: support, user-interface, image

How can I insert image from picture folder of Ubuntu while asking question or answering to question in Ask Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to insert an image. The image can be from your PC or a link in the internet.

Or click the img button to insert an image like this:
[image]

Comment: Really it gave me great relief. I was wondering at FAQ, trying to copy paste and even drag and drop. Thanks! Anwar

Comment: @Namshum Thanks to you too.