# Inserted image in Ask Ubuntu not showing in browser

Tags: support, answer-format, image

I am trying to insert a screenshot to answer a question, using both options as mentioned [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/4047/insert-picture-in-ask-ubuntu). However, the image is not being displayed on browser.

<sub>**Note :** I am uploading image from my computer.</sub>

I am also not able to images submitted by any other users, e.g. I can guess that the [answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/4048/212399) to the question linked above contains an image. But I am not able to see that too.

Is there any browser setting that I am missing here?

Comment: Are they showing up on a different browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're on a network that's blocking Imgur. That's where all the images are hosted. You can verify that by trying to [visit them](http://imgur.com). That would explain why the pop-up isn't working and why you can't view images.

You could upload the images to another host but Stack Exchange has an arrangement with Imgur to host files permanently. This is so we don't end up with a ton of posts that have 404ing images in them.

I think the only sustainable solution is to get the block removed. You could work around it (proxy/vpn/etc) but doing that is probably in violation of your network policy too.

Comment: Thanks @Oli. I am able to see the image that I inserted on a different browser and machine.